# How create annotation file for deep learning?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am in the process of creating a car brand identification project using python and tensorflow (CNN)
I found an example on github https://github.com/satojkovic/DeepLogo
but the problem I can not understand how to create the .txt annotation file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48C5W.png)

Answer (score 1):

annotation file consists image , brand name ,  location (L, R, H ,W)

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can not find how to generate this file